# data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict Bitcoin data on November. I have the close value of it with list.

```
data =[1373711, 1355049, 1395030, 1413371, 1557985, 1556588, 1483375, 1547957, 1533232, 1529090, 1570134, 1627634, 1631781, 1606814, 1595559, 1671611, 1764541, 1780401, 1781709, 1862131, 1864223, 1837000, 1836412, 1910746, 1873212, 1715062, 1710840, 1771741, 1817748, 1962584]
```

I want to predict for after 7 days. But I don't know how to label these data.

when I label like:

```
X_tr = x[0: len(x) - 7]
y_tr= [i for i in range(len(X_tr))]
X_te = x[len(x) -7:]
y_te = [i for i in range(len(x))]
```

give me the result :

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

How can I label this data in order to predict well?

```
import sklearn.gaussian_process as gp

#     X_tr <-- training observations [# points, # features]
#     y_tr <-- training labels [# points]
#     X_te <-- test observations [# points, # features]
#     y_te <-- test labels [# points]

kernel = gp.kernels.ConstantKernel(1.0, (1e-1, 1e3)) * gp.kernels.RBF(10.0, (1e-3, 1e3))
model = gp.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10, alpha=0.1, normalize_y=True)
model.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
params = model.kernel_.get_params()
y_pred, std = model.predict(X_te, return_std=True)
MSE = ((y_pred-y_te)**2).mean()

print(MSE)
```

The bottom code works with no errors. But the output is not the value I've wanted.

```
X_tr = np.array(x[0: len(x) - 7]).reshape(-1, 1)
y_tr= np.arange(len(X_tr))
X_te = np.array(x[len(x) -7:]).reshape(-1, 1)
y_te =  np.arange(len(X_te))

kernel = gp.kernels.ConstantKernel(1.0, (1e-1, 1e3)) * gp.kernels.RBF(10.0, (1e-3, 1e3))
model = gp.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10, alpha=0.1, normalize_y=True)
second_start_time = time.time()
model.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
params = model.kernel_.get_params()
y_pred, std = model.predict(X_te, return_std=True)
```

output:

```
5.855315314279931
5.855315314279931
5.855315314279931
5.855315314279931
5.855315314279931
5.855315314279931
5.855315314279931
GP    MSE: 68.000 time: 0.124009
```

The result with  autoregressive model is :

```
0 : predict: 1935015.192651, original: 1910746.000000
1 : predict: 2043951.061726, original: 1873212.000000
2 : predict: 2088977.491144, original: 1715062.000000
3 : predict: 2102378.836602, original: 1710840.000000
4 : predict: 2130750.595640, original: 1771741.000000
5 : predict: 2171709.122461, original: 1817748.000000
6 : predict: 2217660.683319, original: 1962584.000000
AR    MSE: 91728108049.238 time: 0.002000
```

I want to know how to label appropriately.

Comment: I think you need to reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: How can I? Can you give me some more explanation or examples?

Comment: `y_tr.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: but the type of the y_tr is a list. List cannot be reshaped like that..

Comment: `np.array(y_tr).reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: I did what you've told me, but I don't think I'm getting the right answer. Could you please check the edited result again?